# Choppy sound via HDMI on Mac Mini 4,1

Tags: 11.10, hdmi, alsa, mac-mini

I get choppy sound output over hdmi with the command.

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

My current configuration can can be found here:
[alsa-info.sh output](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2eda69b513466f3d71709255c5a786c32d947275)

Sound worked after some tweaking with 10.04. After upgrade to 11.10 sound stopped working properly. A fresh installation of 11.10 did not change the situation.

Video over hdmi works without problems.
As soon as I run speaker-test I get fluent sound again. Workaround to trigger speaker-test after login is obvious but I would like a real fix to that problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your cables and hardware. It should be a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem was solved by the OP:**

The following configuration fixed the problem:

1) Added the following line to /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-alsa-siice=hw:0,8
```

2) Added the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp55 enable=1 index=0 position_fix=1
```

The last three parameters actually solved the problem. Before that I had to run speaker-test to get fluent sound. dmesg returned the following error but afterwards sound was okay.

```
hda-intel: Invalid position buffer, using LPIB read method instead.
```

3) I am not sure if this is related but I had temporarily success with the following grub boot parameter in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset noacpi"
```

I am still not sure what the problem was. If anyone could tell me I would like to learn it. Thanks.

Some useful resources:

[ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/gpu-hdmi-audio-document/gpu-hdmi-audio.html](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2eda69b513466f3d71709255c5a786c32d947275)
http://my.opera.com/Hoelli/blog/show.dml/1646577